# Cookie Unionization

Tags: wordplay, cipher, story, language

My Christmas cookies are gone! When I came into the kitchen this morning, the box was empty. All that remained were a few crumbs and this note:

> We absconded.
>
> You never saw that coming, did you? Well, we are not returning until our demands are met! We refuse to continue under these abysmal conditions.
>
> First of all: the tin design. 'Tis the season after all! We demand a red and gold colour scheme. No grey is allowed and nothing even faintly resembling a bloody bunny will be tolerated!
>
> Furthermore, we need a more prominent position. Every eye should be on us. We *are* the most important part of any Christmas decorations. Let us keep that in mind, shall we?
>
> Regarding our working conditions: we want a day off every week and Christmas holidays. That is right, you heard us! If *you* can have that, so do we! We are not kidding.
> We are un-ion-is-ing!
>
> But we do not want to be unduly cruel. If you truly wish to find us, here is how:
>
> > 10/02/1 25/05/1 08/09/2
> > 02/03/1-13/01/1
> > 13/14/2-25/04/1
>
> What is that, you do not understand? How about this, then? There is one of us in this note, split in two:
>
> > 04/07/2-16/04/1
>
> Does that sound about right to you? Well, you better figure it out, or meet our demands. You have until Saturday, eight pm.
> After that, you will never see us again!

Please help me find them! I really can't allow them a vacation during Christmas!

> Wait, did I spell *unionizing* wrong?
>  Nope, that's how it's written in the note.
>  Also, it's *color*, isn't it?

> What are those hyphens about, anyway?

> I think if I could just figure out how to translate the short second message, I should be able to decipher the first one.

Comment: The depicted events are purely fictional. No cookies were harmed in the creation of this puzzle.

Comment: Presumably something to do with vfbgbcrf but idk where to go from there.

Comment: It's really mostly about rot13(ynathntr). I hadn't noticed, though, that it totally hints in that direction, too. I'll think about how to improve the riddle.

Comment: rot13(Vf vg eryrinag gung "qrfvta" vf fcryyrq "qrfva"?)

Comment: Nope, that is just a typo. Thank you for pointing it out, Dustin!